# How to grouping tables in database tools window in PhpStorm

Tags: phpstorm

I'm using **PhpStorm** version **2018.1** and used database tools to manage MySQL databases and their tables.

But because the number of tables is high and growing, I'm looking for a way to grouping them into sub folders for example.

Is there any way to do that in PhpStorm?

Answer (score 1):

The only available grouping options for tables are listed under a "Gear" button:
[image]

Custom grouping isn't supported & there are no requests for this at [JetBrains tracker](http://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issues/WI#newissue=yes). Feel free to submit one!